# Neo4J find unique results

Tags: java, neo4j, cypher

I have a graph that displays a finance relation between companies - the relation of owes , which companies owe money to companies . I seek a unique relations - circles , which are latter closed .So if I owe You money and we find that somehow you owe me money me close the debt . The companies are identified by tax number. For this I use this Cypher query :

```
start n=node(*) 
match p=n-[r:OWES*1..200]->n 
where HAS(n.taxnumber) 
return  extract(s in relationships(p) : s.amount), 
        extract(t in nodes(p) : ID(t)), 
        length(p) ;
```

But I also get results like

```
Company1-Company2-company1-Company-3
```

I display this results back in my java application . Should I maybe hide this results after I parse them in java code - results where one company is shown twice .
This is fine when it comes to logic but I need results where a company is shown only once , I do not want results where I get the same company multiple times . How to modify my Cypher query for that ? What I want is that the company in the results can be only at the beginning and at the end of the result and not somehow circled in the middle .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to check the path-nodes to not contain your start node.

```
start n=node(*) 
match p=n-[:OWES*1..200]->(m), (m)-[r:OWES]->n 
where HAS(n.taxnumber) 

AND NOT(n IN tail(nodes(p)))

return  extract(s in relationships(p) : s.amount) + r.amount, 
        extract(t in nodes(p) : ID(t)) + ID(n), 
        length(p) + 1;
```

Unfortunately there is no subscript in 1.8.2 and only `tail(coll)` no simple way to exclude the last element from a check. That's why I have to break up p and fix your aggregations at the end.

Comment: When I run it as start n=node(*) match p=n-[r:OWES*1..200]->n where HAS(n.taxnumber) AND NOT(n IN nodes(p)[1..-1]) return  extract(s in relationships(p) : s.amount), extract(t in nodes(p) : ID(t)), length(p) ; I get Unclosed parenthesis error...

Comment: I use Neo4j-cypher-1.8.2.jar in my application

Comment: I upgraded to 2.0 run the query start n=node(*) match p=n-[r:OWES*1..200]->n where  HAS(n.taxnumber) AND NOT(n IN nodes(p)[1..-1]) return extract(s in relationships(p) : s.amount), extract(t in nodes(p) : ID(t)), length(p) ; and got Invalid input '(': expected an identifier character, whitespace, NodeLabel, '.', node labels, '[', "=~", IN, IS, '*', '/', '%', '^', '+', '-', '<', '>', "<=", ">=", '=', "<>", "!=", AND, XOR, OR, WHERE, '|', ')' or ','